# Python pipes in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a decentralised tool that tracks the IPs of other computers running the code, to explore decentralisation. The problem is with piping information form the sub process to the main program. I have coded a smaller program to simulate the problem. the first code segment is the main process which starts the sub process and listens for traffic in the pipe. The second segment is the sub process which sends data back to the main process using print(). But the data never arrives.

```
# main process
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
listener = Popen(['python3', 'a.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
i = 1
while i == 1:
    stdout, stderr = listener.communicate()
    print(stdout)
```

sub process:

```
# subprocess "a.py"
from time import sleep
i = 1
while i == 1: 
    sleep(1)
    print('new:192.168.2.24', flush=True)
    print('new:192.168.2.24', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) waits for the process to terminate. From the docs (emphasis mine)

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate and set the returncode attribute.** The optional input argument should be data to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child. If streams were opened in text mode, input must be a string. Otherwise, it must be bytes.

You'll want to read from [`Popen.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) directly.

```
print(listener.stdout.readline())
```